# How Can I Create a Tuckey Passthrough Rewrite Rule for Just the Root of a Folder that Already Exists on the Filesystem?

Tags: url-rewriting, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I'd like to create a Tuckey rewrite rule that matches only when the URL points to the root of a particular subfolder like this: http://localhost/foo *(or http://localhost/foo/)*

In this scenario, the /foo folder already exists and I need to make sure static assets under the /foo folder can still be accessible as normal.  For example "http://localhost/foo/img/flower.jpg".

Here's what I've come up with so far, but it isn't working:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE urlrewrite PUBLIC "-//tuckey.org//DTD UrlRewrite 4.0//EN" "http://tuckey.org/res/dtds/urlrewrite4.0.dtd">
<urlrewrite>
    <!-- Turn foo/ into /index.cfm/foo/ -->
    <rule>
        <from>^/foo$</from>
        <to type="passthrough">/index.cfm/foo</to>
    </rule>
</urlrewrite>
```

I suspect I may need to make some tweaks to the regex in the `<from>` section.  Any help you could offer would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE urlrewrite PUBLIC "-//tuckey.org//DTD UrlRewrite 4.0//EN" "http://tuckey.org/res/dtds/urlrewrite4.0.dtd">
<urlrewrite>
    <!-- Turn foo/ into /index.cfm/foo/ -->
    <rule>
        <from>^/foo/$</from>
        <to type="passthrough">/index.cfm/foo</to>
    </rule>
</urlrewrite>
```

You have to add a slash before the `$`.  This should execute the rule for the following paths:

- /foo
- /foo/

It will ignore the following paths:

- /foo/img/
- /foo/img/flower.jpg